# Quorum read consistency in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, consistency

I'm new to distributed databases and there are a couple of things I couldn't figure out.
We're developing an application and need to select the right database,
this application needs strong consistency on financial data related to users, like deposit and withdraws.
I am wondering about **tunable consistency** in Cassandra, specifically *quorum* level of consistency.
Imagine the following scenario:
Replication factor is *3*.
Initial balance of a user *John* is *10* on all replicas.
At time **t1**, an update is happening on John's balance reducing it to *7* (CL=quorum),
Simultaneously, at time **t1**, a read operation is being run with consistency level set on *quorum* which is *2* in this case.
Is it possible that the replica on the node where *update* query is executing on, is not selected for the quorum?
If so, Is it right to assume that the result of `read` operation would be 10 because there's no write lock?
Overall I'd like to know if it is possible for *John* to somehow *exploit* this and spend more than his account's balance.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the consistency level for update operation?

Comment: @AlexOtt Thanks for reminding me! I've edited the question, CL for the update operation is set on quorum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With having QUORUM for both read & write requrests you achieve strong consistency per following equation `R + W > N`, where `R` - read replica count, `W` - write replica count, and `N` - replication factor.

If you write with QUORUM, then 2 nodes will get fresh data, and when you read with QUORUM, then one node may have the old data, and one will have fresh data - Cassandra will detect discrepancy & use the newest version.

Comment: So basically my concern for 'double spending' problem due to old data is irrelevant. Am I getting this right?

Comment: Yes - you are right. Although for money I maybe prefer to use consistency level ALL for writes...

Comment: Does this apply for MySQL master slave replication as well? Is there any tool to implement strong consistency across master and slaves using quorum for MySQL?

Comment: Don’t know... haven’t used MySQL for a long time